# Rating System with Elo, better alternatives?

Tags: algorithm, rating

I'm working on a rating algorithm. I have a set of exercises. They are all categorized in levels (1 = easiest, 5 = hardest).

Users get shown two exercises and should decide which one is harder or if both are equal. Based on user ratings, the levels should get adjusted.

What I've done:
I experimented with the Elo rating.

My Questions:
Are there any better algorithms for doing this use case? (found nothing so far)

Thanks in advance and cheers.
Toby

Comment: This looks fun, but open-ended.  I would suggest an Elo rating where you cycle through the comparisons multiple times, each time making the Elo adjustment smaller.  That removes the effects of the order of the vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to solve the problem in a simple yet (I hope) effective way.

First, you only update an exercise rating when the vote is different that what the system actually expects. From now on, I will only considers the cases where the user output differs from what the system actually expects.

Second, I would give more weight to the votes where the two levels have a big difference. A wrong expectation on two esercises with rating 2 and 3 should have less impact than a wrong expectation on two exercises with rating 1 and 5.

That said, my algorithm would be along the lines of:

1- A constant percentage is set, let's call it `increment`. It establishes the percentage of impact that a vote has, and can be modified along the way based on the number of users.

2- For an "unexpected" vote, I would calculate the difference between the original levels (minimum of 1).

```
diff = max(1, abs(ex1.level - ex2.level))
```

3- I would update each exercise rating by a percentage, based on the multiplication of `increment` and `diff`.

```
if (ex1 level expected bigger)
    ex1.rating = ex1.rating + diff*increment;
else
    ex1.rating = ex1.rating - diff*increment;
```

Rating would be a float, and level would be the rounding of `rating`:

```
ex1.level = round(ex1.rating)
```

**Example**:

let's set `increment = 0.1`. `exA`, with a rating of 2.0 and level 2 is compared with `exB`, rating of 3.0 and level 3.

The first user selects `exB` as the hardest. Nothing changes, because it is the result expected by the system.

The second user selects `exA`. It is not the expected result. The difference between the two exercises is 1, so the rating is modified by a factor 1*0.1 = 0.1,
resulting in a `exA.rating = 2.1` for `exB.rating = 2.9`